# Create Custom Unique ID

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, custom-list, unique

I have a requirement to create a unique ID for a list item in SharePoint 2010 where the ID is in the format of [ACC]-[YEAR]-[SEQUENTIAL_INTEGER] but the [SEQUENTIAL_INTEGER] part needs to reset to 1 each year?

For example, 
ACC2014000001, ACC2014000002 .. ACC2014000100 and when 2014 ends the integer part reverts to 1 so in 2015 the unique ID's would look as follows: 
ACC2015000001, ACC2015000002 .. ACC2014000131

What's the most appropriate way to do this in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: If you can write server side code then Event Receiver is the best option as you need to check the current year, maximum sequential number etc.

Comment: @AvijitSur I know about event receivers but part of my question is how do I do the reset the sequential integer part after each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hers is the code you need to use in Event Receiver...

```
int newID = 0;

                    //Get current year
                    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
                    //Your list name
                    string listName = "Test";
                    //CAML string assuming 'Title' is the column contains unique ID
                    string camlString = @"<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>"+currentYear.ToString()+"</Value></Contains></Where>";
                    //Get the list
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);

                    //Trigger query and get the result in SPListItemCollection
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = camlString;
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

                    //if already have items with current year
                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //convert the SPListItemCollection into List to support LINQ
                        List<SPListItem> listItems = items.Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();
                        //get max id from the result as it will be the max unique value
                        var maxID = (from l in listItems
                                     select l.ID).Max();

                        var item = (from l in listItems
                                           where l.ID == maxID
                                           select l).ToList();
                        //get SPListItem
                        SPListItem maxItem = item[0];
                        //get unique ID from the item
                        string uniqStr = maxItem["Title"].ToString();
                        //extract max unique number 
                        newID = int.Parse(uniqStr.Substring(7));
                    }

                    //increase the unique number
                    newID += 1;

                    //construct the new unique ID
                    string uniqueID = "ACC" + currentYear.ToString() + newID.ToString("D6");

                    //use uniqueID to update your custom unique ID column
```

Comment: Can you explain what the "D6" means in your proposed answer and if the answer works when there are no dashes in the ID?

Comment: I have updated the code which will now take UniqueID without "-". ToString("D6") provides integer formatting with leading zeros...check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865325/random-nr-for-000001-000100

Comment: This almost works but as a test I changed and existing item ID ACC2015000006 to ACC2014000006 and added a new item.  The expected outcome was that the new ID would be ACC2015000001 (as the requirement is to revert to 1 at the beginning of each year) but the result was that the new item ID was set to ACC2015000006.

Comment: Is there any other items with ID ACC2015######?

Comment: Yes. So I'm confused as to what is supposed to happen.  When I deleted all other ACC2015###### items it increments correctly.